# PHP mail() function and execute sendmail with different configuration

Tags: php, sendmail, ssmtp

Is there any way to execute PHP `mail()` function with some arguments so sendmail will load different configuration? Something similar like Python can do with a code below

`ssmtp = "/usr/sbin/ssmtp"
args = [ssmtp, '-v', '-v', '-v', '-C', '/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp-locrelay.conf', to_address]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary can be changed with the [sendmail_path](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) directive and command-line arguments go as [$additional_parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )